# Concatenating two dictionaries with same keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, concatenation

**Edit: TL;DR**

What I have:

```
dict_1 = {'file1': {'word1': 5, 'word2: 3'}, 'file2': {'word1': 12, 'word2: 0'}}


dict_2 = {'file1': {'total_words': 11}, 'file2': {'total_words': 18}}
```

What I want

```
concat_dict = {'file1': {'word1': 5, 'word2: 3', 'total_words' : 11}, 'file2': {'word1': 12, 'word2: 0', 'total_words' : 18}}
```

Which has added a associated value from `dict_2` to the common key in `dict_1`.
I have a dictionary that is composed of text file names and the word-count of specific words in those files.

**Original post**

I want to add also a count for the total words in each file (value for each key), in addition to the specific words in each file, how would I do that?

My code:

```
# dict_one = previously defined
# filter_words = previously defined
out={}
for k, v in dict_one.items():
    #create empty list
    new = []
    #for each filter word
    for i in filter_words:
        new.extend(re.findall(r"{}".format(i),v) )

    out[k] = dict(Counter(new))

# count total number of words
total_dict = {k: len(v) for k,v in dict_one.items()}
```

Basically, I want to concatenate total_dict{} and out{} dictionaries, as they have the same keys but I'm unsure how.

Also: I haven't gone through this code in a while, but I forgot what this expression does:

```
new.extend(re.findall(r"{}".format(i),v) )
```

I know it's extending the list, but im confused by the arguments of re.findall:

```
r"{}".format(i),v)
```

what does this mean/do?

Comment: In this particular example, `"{}".format(i)` is similar to `str(i)`; The `r` is unnecessary. See [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension and the approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/189418) to merge the internal dicts:

```py
dict_1 = {'file1': {'word1': 5, 'word2': '3'}, 'file2': {'word1': 12, 'word2': '0'}}
dict_2 = {'file1': {'total_words': 11}, 'file2': {'total_words': 18}}

concat_dict = {k:{**dict_1[k], **dict_2[k]} for k in dict_1}
concat_dict
```

Output:

```
{'file1': {'word1': 5, 'word2': '3', 'total_words': 11},
 'file2': {'word1': 12, 'word2': '0', 'total_words': 18}}
```

Comment: I'm getting a strange error I can't seem to find online:

**TypeError: 'int' object is not a mapping**

Comment: Your example had a couple of typos that I had to fix. For example, this string `'word2: 3'` should be `'word2': '3'`. Try to fix those or copy-paste my code to check that it runs.

Comment: Copying and pasting your code actually works. But it doesn't seem to be working when I use my actual dictionaries. For example, I have: 

`dict_1 = {'file1': {'word1': 2}}

dict_2 = {'file1': 190952}

concat = {}

concat = {k:{**dict_1[k], **dict_2[k]} for k in dict_1}`

Which returns the error 'int' object is not a mapping. I copied and pasted those key/value pairs into my dict_1 and dict_2 creations from the console.

Comment: Sorry! I just figured it out. My second dictionary doesn't have a  proper key-value pair in the same format as the original dictionary.

Comment: Exactly. If your `dict_2` is instead like the one in your example, you can use `concat = {k:{**dict_1[k], **{'total_words': dict_2[k]}} for k in dict_1}`

Comment: I know this is a separate question altogether, but would you know how to get my `dict_2 = {'file1': 190952}` so that it's `dict_2 = {'file1': {'total_words': 190952}}` ?

to create `dict_2` I used `dict_2 = {k: len(v) for k,v in dict_one.items()}`

Comment: You can create `dict_2` as `dict_2 = {k: {'total_words':len(v)} for k,v in dict_one.items()}`